# Create Unit test for AccountController : ApiController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a WebApi project in Visual Studio 2015 which automatically generated class `AccountController` (which is a subclass of `ApiController`).  My problem is that I can't create the unit tests for this class.

How can I create unit tests for the methods in this class?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you create the unit tests for that class?

Comment: The following article / tutorial covers Unit Testing of a WebApi application: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api -- and another: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch17.html#_getting_started_with_unit_testing_in_visual_studio

Comment: i'm a beginner in this technology, in need how call Register method from my test method.